# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeStoryCell parentViewController]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on adding a CollectionView into a custom container that I've created. I've used the Container before to host UITableView's but never a CollectionView. Didn't it'd be so hard either. Just thought I had to switch some words around poof it would work! But sadly thats not the way things. Instead I just receive crash notices.

My program keeps crashing right here.

```
//0. Remove the current Detail View Controller showed
if(self.currentDetailViewController){
    [self removeCurrentDetailViewController];
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why?

here is my code

```
  #import "YourHome.h"
  #import "HomePostTable.h"
  #import "HomeStoryView.h"
  @interface YourHome ()

  @end

@implementation YourHome

-(void)queryParseMethod {
    NSLog(@"start query");
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
   // [query whereKey:@"photo" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        UsersFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"%@", UsersFilesArray);
        //PFObject *imageObject = [PFUser currentUser];

        for (PFObject *imageObject in UsersFilesArray) {
          //  NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            PFFile *ImageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"photo"];


            [ImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {

                    _ProfilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


                    Background.image = _ProfilePic.image;
                    _ProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = _ProfilePic.frame.size.width / 2;
                    _ProfilePic.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    _ProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
                    _ProfilePic.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

                }
                else {

                    NSLog(@"errrrrrr");
                }                    

            }];
        }

        }
    }];
}
     - (void)presentDetailController1:(UICollectionViewController*)detailVC{

     //0. Remove the current Detail View Controller showed
    if(self.currentDetailViewController){
        [self removeCurrentDetailViewController];
    }

    //1. Add the detail controller as child of the container
    [self addChildViewController:detailVC];

    //2. Define the detail controller's view size
    detailVC.view.frame = [self frameForDetailController];

    //3. Add the Detail controller's view to the Container's detail view and save a reference to the detail View Controller
    [self.detailView addSubview:detailVC.view];
    self.currentDetailViewController = detailVC;

     //4. Complete the add flow calling the function didMoveToParentViewController
     [detailVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
 - (void)removeCurrentDetailViewController{
   NSLog(@"Go");

   //1. Call the willMoveToParentViewController with nil
   //   This is the last method where your detailViewController can perform    some operations before neing removed
   [self.currentDetailViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    //2. Remove the DetailViewController's view from the Container
   [self.currentDetailViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

   //3. Update the hierarchy"
   //   Automatically the method didMoveToParentViewController: will be called on the detailViewController)
    [self.currentDetailViewController removeFromParentViewController];

}
- (CGRect)frameForDetailController{

   CGRect detailFrame = self.detailView.bounds;

    return detailFrame;

  }

 - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self queryParseMethod];


      HomeStoryView *detailOne = [[HomeStoryView alloc]init];

     [self presentDetailController1:detailOne];

  }
```

Comment: Reading your title here, why would your HomeStory**Cell** class have a parentViewController method?

Comment: Thats what confuses me..I never called anything like that. Theres barely any code in HomeStoryCell

Comment: Somewhere, likely another class, you are invoking parentViewController on an instance of HomeViewCell.  Or maybe IB, you could have an instances class set incorrectly